# How to design a closed rectangular box of minimum cost using Lagrange Multipliers

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

> Suppose the box is to be of volume $V_0$ cubic cm; and the cost of material for the front and back sides is $b$ dollars per square cm, $c$ dollars per square cm for the left and right two sides, and $d$ dollars per square cm for the top and bottom sides.  Note that $V_0$, $b$, $c$ and $d$ are just arbitrary constants.

This is the task and so far all I've been able to get together is the following equation:

$$f(x,y,z)=2bxy+2cyz+2dxz$$

$$g(x,y,z)=xyz=V_0$$

$$\overrightarrow {\nabla}f = f_x + f_y + f_z$$

$$f_x = 2by+2dz$$

$$f_y = 2bx + 2cz$$

$$f_z = 2cy + 2dx$$

$$\overrightarrow {\nabla}g = g_x+g_y+g_z$$

$$g_x=yz = \lambda yz$$

$$g_y=xz = \lambda xz$$

$$g_z=xy = \lambda xy$$

So then I set the corresponding functions equal to each other and get:

$$2by+2dz=\lambda yz \;;\frac{2by+2dz}{\lambda} = yz$$

$$2bx+2cz=\lambda xz \;;\frac{2bx+2cz}{\lambda} = xz$$

$$2cy+2dx=\lambda xy \;;\frac{2cy+2dx}{\lambda} = xy$$

But I'm lost with where to go from here.  Any hints or tips?

Comment: use the constraint $xyz=V_0$ to simplify the algebra

Comment: I completely understand it now!  It took me a while to figure out what you were doing but its all crystal clear now.  Amazing I was hung up on the algebra all this time!  Thanks @WW1

Comment: @WW1 Sorry and I know you're probably busy, but I wonder why $V_0$ is negative?  That seems odd to me

Comment: $V_0$ isn't negative $\lambda $ is .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when constrained to the surface $xyz=V_0$

$f(x,y,z)= 2V_0(\frac{b}{z}+\frac{c}{x}+\frac{d}{y})$
so $\vec \nabla f(x, y, z) =-2V_0(\frac{c}{x^2}, \frac{d}{y^2},\frac{b}{z^2} ) $

$g(x, y, z) = xzy \\  \implies \vec \nabla g(x, y, z) = (yx, xz, xy)$

the gradient constrained to the surface is $\vec \nabla g(x, y, z) = V_0(\frac 1x, \frac 1y, \frac 1z)  $

So $$  \frac{-2V_0c }{x^2}=\frac{\lambda V_0}x \implies x= \frac{-2c}{\lambda}
\\y= \frac{-2d}{\lambda}
\\z=  \frac{-2b}{\lambda}
\\ \text{ and } \frac{-8bcd}{\lambda^3}=V_0 \implies \lambda = \left(   \frac{-8bcd}{V_0} \right)^\frac 13$$

Comment: I edited more of my original question, can you tell me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Heh... it looks like you just did some fancy algebra to factor out $V_0$ to simplify solving the equations!

Answer (score 1):

$$f(x,y,z)= 2bxy+2cyz+2dxz$$
is the (cost) function to be maximized

The constraint is
$$ g(x,y,z)=xyz=V_0 $$

now solve $\vec \nabla f = \lambda \vec \nabla g$

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH for this hint.  You have no idea how much this has helped me.  I just want to make sure I'm understanding, though.  So I'm going to be taking the gradient of both $f(x,y,z)$ and $g(x,y,z)$ and then multiplying $\lambda g(x,y,z)$ and setting this equal to the gradient of $f$?

Comment: yes - those 3 equations together with $xyz=V_0$ gives you 4 equations to find your 4 unknowns.

Comment: Am I crazy, or is the algebra for this problem extremely hairy