# How to design a closed rectangular box of minimum cost without Lagrange Multipliers

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

> Suppose the box is to be of volume $V_0$ cubic cm; and the cost of material for the front and back sides is $b$ dollars per square cm, $c$ dollars per square cm for the left and right two sides, and $d$ dollars per square cm for the top and bottom sides.  Note that $V_0$, $b$, $c$ and $d$ are just arbitrary constants.

What are the ramifications of:

1.)$b = c = d$

2.)$b = c = 2d$

3.)$b = 2c = 3d$

I got help here [How to design a closed rectangular box of minimum cost using Lagrange Multipliers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1555656/how-to-design-a-closed-rectangular-box-of-minimum-cost-using-lagrange-multiplier) to do it using Lagrange Multipliers, but how do I do it without?

Below is my attempt, but I get a discriminant of $0$ which means the test failed.

$$f(x,y,z)=2bxy+2cyz+2dxz$$

$$V_0=xyz$$

$$\frac{2bV_0}{z}+\frac{2cV_0}{x}+\frac{2dV_0}{y}=0$$

Next I solved for $z$:

$$z=-\frac{bx}{c}-\frac{by}{d}$$

Now I took this and plugged it back into my original equation so that it is now a function of two variables instead of three:

$$f(x,y)=2bxy+2cy\left(-\frac{bx}{c}-\frac{by}{d}\right)+2dx\left(-\frac{bx}{c}-\frac{by}{d}\right)$$

I then simplified:

$$-\frac{2cy^2b}{d}-\frac{2dx^b}{c}-2xby$$

I then found all of the partials:

$$f_x=\frac{-4xbd}{c}-2by$$

$$f_y=\frac{-4ybc}{d}-2xb$$

$$f_{xx}=\frac{-4bd}{c}$$

$$f_{yy}=\frac{-4bc}{d}$$

$$f_{xy}=-2b$$

Finally, I found the discriminant:

$$D(x,y)=\frac{-4bd}{c}\left(\frac{-4bc}{d}\right)-(-2b)^2$$

$$D(x,y)=-4\left(\frac{b^2cd}{cd}\right)+4b^2=0$$

Did I make a computational error, or am I'm doing this completely wrong?

Comment: When you have a problem with an equality constraint and you do not want to use Lagrange multipliers, you must eliminate one variable from the constraint (this is not always feasible), rewrite the objective function based on all other variables and cancel the corresponding partial derivatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The replacement was not done the right way. You should replace say $z$ in your first expression for $f(x,y,z)$ by $\frac{V_0}{xy}$.

Then we need to minimize the two variable function $g(x,y)$, where
$$g(x,y)=2bxy+\frac{2cV_0}{x}+\frac{2dV_0}{y}.$$

Comment: Thanks for the tips!  How did you get the replacement $\frac{V_0}{xy}$?

Comment: You are welcome. We are told that the volume is $V_0$, Thus $xyz=V_0$ (you wrote this down). Solve for $z$ by dividing both sides by $xy$. We get $z=\frac{V_0}{xy}$. I then substituted in the expression $f(x,y,z)$ for cost. There was a bit of cancellation in the second term and third term.

Comment: Wow... I cannot believe I overlooked the simplicity there.  Thanks for pointing this out to me!

Comment: OK, so using your suggestions and taking the partials of $g(x,y)$ I came up  with $D(x,y)=\frac{16cdV^2_0}{x^3y^3}-4b^2$.  Assuming this is correct, do I test the ramifications (above in my original post) by just plugging the various tests into my discriminant?  I'm just confused as to the answer I got for the discriminant and not sure how to determine if I'm working with a max or min.

Comment: Unfortunately not right.  Looking at $g(x,y)$ it is obvious there is no max, for making $x$ very close to $0$ makes the cost huge. Take the partial with respect to $x$, set it equal to $0$. Take the partial with respect to $y$, set it equal to $0$. Two equations in the two unknowns $x$ and $y$. Relatively easy to solve for $x$ and $y$.

Comment: OK, sorry it has taken me so long to get back to you.  I just got around to working this again based on what you said.  Now I when I solve $g_x=0$ for $y$ I get $y=\frac{4bcV_0}{x^2}$.  I plugged this into $g_y=0$ and I got $x=0$ and $x=\sqrt[3]{\frac{16b^3c^2V_0}{d}}$.  Does this look better?

Comment: For sure $x=0$ is not a solution. A quick calculation (do check) gives $x=\sqrt[3]{c^2V_0/(bd)}$.  For taking the partial with respect to $x$ gives $by=cV_0/x^2$. The same with respect to $y$ gives $bx=dV_0/y^2$. Multiplying the $y$ stuff together and the $x$ stuff together gives after some cancellation $d/y=c/x$ and you can do the rest.

Comment: I get nearly the same partials with the exception of the $2$'s.  $by=\frac{4cV_0}{x^2}$ and when I divide the $b$ through I get $y=\frac{4bcV_0}{x^2}$

Comment: Never mind, I found my algebraic mistake.  $y=\frac{cV_0}{bx^2}$

Comment: I automatically cancelled the $2$'s without commenting.

Comment: OK, I finally got the correct critical point $\left(\sqrt[3]{\frac{c^2V_0}{bd}}, \frac{cV_0}{bx^2}\right)$.  Now I understand this is where the global minimum occurs, but in view of the equations, how do I test the ramifications?

Comment: Really you should give the second coordinate (dimension) $y$ explicitly in terms of the parameters $b,c,d,V_0$, and probably also the third dimension $z$. That will clearly exhibit the symmetries. Now you can compute what the minimum cost is for the various scenarios.

Comment: OK so instead use: $y=\frac{cV_0}{b\left(\sqrt[3]{\frac{c^2V_0}{bd}}\right)^2}$?